How to get Background Image in Android studio for Watchface
I'm trying to develop a Watchface in Android Studio. When I'm trying to add an image as background in my watch face, it is not showing up:
<WatchFace width="450" height="450">
  <Metadata key="CLOCK_TYPE" value="DIGITAL"/>
  <Metadata key="PREVIEW_TIME" value="10:08:32"/>



  <Scene>
    <Image resource="background1" x="225" y="225" width="900" height="512" alpha="255">
      <Variant mode="AMBIENT" target="alpha" value="255" />
    </Image>

  </Scene>
</WatchFace>

I searched the web / AI / the developer Homepage from Android:
Android documentation
The Image is located in @res/drawable and is showing up in android studio correctly.
What I'm doing wrong? Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

You should use PartImage as a container for your Image(s):
<WatchFace clipShape="CIRCLE" height="450" width="450">
  <Scene>
    <PartImage x="0" y="0" width="450" height="450">
      <!-- Hide the image when in ambient mode -->
      <Variant mode="AMBIENT" target="alpha" value="0" />
      <!-- Use image from res/drawables/background.png -->
      <Image resource="background" />
    </PartImage>

    <!-- Hands and other details go here -->
  </Scene>
</WatchFace>

